# Simple Website Comments Section

Tags: php, html, css

I have a very simple website, and would like to create a 'Comments' section to it. Currently I have a HTML document and a CSS document running the site.

I have a little knowledge of PHP, and would like to keep this as simple as possible - i.e: saving comments to a text file perhaps? But not sure.

Can someone please suggest the simplest way of adding the comments options in.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The simplest way would be using something like WordPress or ExpressionEngine that have that built in.

Comment: What are they exactly...

Comment: Publishing platforms. http://wordpress.org/ is probably the most popular and easy to install, assuming you have a database you can use.

Comment: ... or Facebook: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Comment: [TextPattern](http://textpattern.com/features/340/for-web-developers) also is popular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It requires a MySQL database (which, if you're developing with PHP, is something that's better to get a cursory knowledge of sooner rather than later), but Commentator is a pretty nice, simple comment script. See: http://ratherodd.com/commentator/

Comment: Link is dead. Project seems to be moved to: https://github.com/raffles/Commentator

Answer (score 1):

You can use Facebook Connect to add comments to an existing page: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/472 (Updated Link)

I found that post by searching google for "add facebook comments to your site"

Comment: That's apparently an old version of that code; see: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/472

Comment: Thank you for bringing that to attention.

Answer (score 0):

You actually can do this very easily using **file_get_contents()** and **file_put_contents()**.  Using only a flat text file and ***no*** database.

I set up an example page at:
http://staticchaos.freeoda.com/php/

Comment: You should also include relevant code sections in your answer for future reference and easier access.